# Atomless probability measure

Tags: probability, measure-theory, probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

Assume that $m$ is an atomless probability measure on $\mathbb{R}^{d}$. Let $\left( X_{1},\ldots ,X_{d}\right) $ be a random vector with law $m$. Are the marginal cumulative distribution functions of $\left( X_{1},\ldots ,X_{d}\right)$ continuous? I know how to see this when $d=1$ but I have had a hard time with the general case.

Related with this. Let $F$ be a cumulative distribution function on $\mathbb{R}^{d}$. Can we descompose $F$ as $F=F_{c}+F_{d}$, where $F_{c}$ is a continuous cumulative distribution function and $F_{d}$ is a pure atomic cumulative (i.e., discrete) distribution function? Again, I know that this is true for the case $d=1$.

Thanks for any advice that you can give.

Comment: What do you mean by marginal distributions? The CDF for each $X_k$, or for each collection $(X_{k_1},\dots,X_{k_m})$?

Comment: The CDF for each $X_{k}$. Sorry, I was not precise in the sentence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> No.

If $X_1=0$ with full probability and the CDF of $X_2$ is continuous then the distribution of $(X_1,X_2)$ is atomless.